# What is const when you declare a "pointer type" formal (function) parameter "like an const array"?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, constants, function-prototypes

What is `const` when you declare a "pointer type" formal (function) parameter "like an const array"?

I.e.: If T is a type identifier, then is:

```
void f(const T arr[]);
```

equivalent to:

```
void f(const T * const arr);
```

or

```
void f(const T * arr);
```

or

```
void f(T * const arr);
```

And how can one to decrypt the C/C++ standards to find this equivalents? :-)

Are there differences between C and C++ and between the different incarnations of the standards regarding the meaning of the declarations above? (for C - the standards of ANSI C89 and later are relevant)

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.*

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking, "What is const?" What does const have to do with this?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Well - the `const` declaration normally provides write access restrictions to a variable or a formal parameter. If the variable/formal is a pointer, you can either protect the value of the pointer or the value of the object pointed to, or both. Formal parameters that "look like" arrays are actually pointers. I ask if the `const` declaration then applies to the value of the pointer, or to the values of the pointed object(s) or both.

Comment: @EOF does that mean that: `const T * const arr` is equivalent to `const T arr[const]`and `T * const arr` is equivalent to `T arr[const]`? If so, does this hold for older ANSI C also? And is this commonly used/ideomatic? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @MarkA.: The same provision is found in C99 draft standard n1256, `6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)`. I don't have older standards available, but since POSIX requires a C99 compiler, any sane environment should provide one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I should say that:

```
void f(int const* p);
```

and

```
void f(const int* p);
```

have the same meaning and it means that it's a pointer to a value that you cannot change.

There is antoher way to declare pointer:

```
void f(int* const p);
```

And it means the constant pointer and you can't assign it to another address.

As for your question, that code below

```
void f(const T arr[]);
```

will be converted into

```
void f(const T* arr);
```

It will be a pointer to a **first element** of your array

Answer (score 0):

For C++ (at the moment the question is also tagged as C):

There are three different kinds of equivalence involved here. [1] The `const T arr[]` formal argument type decays to `T const* arr`, which therefore is equivalent in the context of formal argument type. [2] `T const* arr` is equivalent to `const T* arr`, which is another syntax expressing the same. [3] In the context of *function type* the formal argument type in `T const* arr` is equivalent to `T const* const arr`, because top level `const` is discarded for the purpose of determining function type. I.e. two function declarations that differ in this way denote the same function.

Comment: I am not sure  why you and @Stivius are stressing case [2] - as I think I am not being ambiguous about. [3] I do not really understand. But my main question is answered with [1]. :-) Do you know if the standards differ on this behavior?

Comment: Re [3], that's always been so in C++. Sorry I didn't notice that  you also had tagged your question C. They are two **different languages**. There is **no such language** as "C/C++". Please remove the C tag.

Comment: I would like to keep C and C++ because I have to handle this interface in both languages. My HOPE is that the answer regarding this very topic is: "C and C++ do not differ here" :-)

Answer (score 0):

`T * const arr` means `arr` should not change.
`const T * arr` means `*arr` should not be changed.
`const T * const arr` means neither `arr` nor `*arr` should be changed.

So which is like `arr` in `void f(const T arr[]);`?
It is like one of the above 3.  Make your selection before mousing over the below.

> `void f(const T *arr);`

---

> And how can one to decrypt the C/C++ standards to find this equivalents?

Reading the standards a number of times helps.  A useful site for a given instance is [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+f%28const+int+*%29%3B)

```
// declare f as function (pointer to const int) returning void
void f(const int *);
```

---

> Are there differences between C and C++ and between the different incarnations of the standards?

Yes, of course, as C/C++ are different languages.  C++ has reference variables.  Early C did not have `const`, etc.

Comment: I meant if these 2 languages differ in THIS point. Regarding early C i will add that I only want to know for C89 and later.

Comment: @Mark A. Suggest adding those clarifications to your post.