# Applying `const` CV-qualifier to decaying array-style `T arr[]` function parameter (intended to decay to `T * const arr`)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'll start by pointing out that this question is purely **out of curiosity**, in so hoping to avoid discussions such as

> *"Consider staying away from `new`/dynamic arrays, and use fit-for-purpose stdlib containers instead, e.g. `std::vector`."*

or

> *"Why would you want to use `int arr[]` parameter syntax on the first place? I always thought that it is considered to be one of the confusing abominations."*

---

#### Decaying an array-style function parameter to `T * const arr`?

If I'm not wrong, the function signatures in the two following functions–intended to be called with a dynamically allocated C-style array–are equivalent due to decay, the first argument being (explicitly or by decay) a raw pointer to `int`.

```
// A) mutable raw ptr to mutable elements
void foo(int * arr, unsigned n)
{
  // ...
  arr = nullptr; // legal
}

// B) mutable raw ptr to mutable elements
void foo(int arr[], unsigned n)
      /* decays to int * arr */
{
  // ...
  arr = nullptr; // legal
}

// ... used e.g. as
int * arr = new int[3]{1, 2, 3}; // c++11
foo(arr, 3);
delete[] arr;
```

Now, let's say for some reason we would like the raw pointer (which has been passed to the function as a copy by value) to be a `const` pointer (e.g. for correctness). For **A)**, this is straight-forward:

```
// A') const raw ptr to mutable elements
void foo(int * const arr, unsigned n)
{
  arr = nullptr; // illegal, OK!
  // ...
}
```

For **B)** however, I haven't been able to perform this modification.

**Question**:

- Is it possible to specify an "array-type" function parameter (intended for a dynamic array argument) that decays into `T * const arr`?

*(I'm naturally happy to receive a proper duplicate target that answers this; I wasn't able to find one myself. The [closest one I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794733) doesn't quite answer the above, as far as I can tell).*

Comment: Why would you want to use `int arr[]` parameter syntax on the first place? I always thought that it is considered to be one of the confusing abominations.

Comment: @VTT I guess my initial remark ended up a bit too unclear, after all: I have no desire to use this syntax in practice, I'm just curious :)

Comment: Your question flips between `T const *` and `T * const` which are two completely different things.

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks for feedback, I thought I reviewed myself good enough not to perform this mixup, but it typo-ed it's way into a single "flip" in the Subsection title! Edited, thanks. I'm only interested in the `const` pointer case (not pointer to `const`).

Comment: AFAIK in C99 one can use `int arr[const]`. It's not possible to do this in C++.

Comment: You say "apart from semantics" but actually the semantics are the same

Comment: @dfri I'm not sure what you're talking about, "semantics" means the defined behaviour of the code and they are both the same.

Comment: @M.M thanks for your patience, I've mixed in "intent" as a part of (non-formal) semantics, but thanks to your feedback and reading up on semantics in the context of CS, I realize this not right. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this, it would be useless syntax, and since neither the top-level const nor the array type is actually part of the function signature it would just be misleading.

If you want to declare the parameter as a non-modifiable pointer then do that. Don't write some other type which is decayed to something different.

You can still declare it using the array for if you think there's some reason to do that, and then add the const in the definition:

```
// declaration
void foo(int arr[], unsigned n);

// definition
void foo(int * const arr, unsigned n)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to understand that arrays are pointers are not the same thing. The "decay" you're talking about is a transformation on the parameters:

> After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”.
>   After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type.

Notice the lack of "cv-qualifier-seq", which implies that it doesn't make sense to transform a const array to a const pointer (whatever that means).

Comment: Thanks, that makes better sense.

Answer (score 2):

Even more confusion with array syntax:

```
using t_arrp = int *;

void foop(t_arrp const arr, unsigned n)
{
//  arr = nullptr; // illegal
}

using t_arr = int[];

void fooa(t_arr const arr, unsigned n)
{
    arr = nullptr; // fine
}
```

Comment: But this is just obscuring type information using aliases (Item 16 @ Meyers Effective ... :) ) to construct two entirely separately CV-qualified function signatures. Anyway, it does put some extra weight onto the point of your comment to the question (to avoid using this syntax!).

Comment: @dfri Actually I think there is a paper mentioning such an inconsistency with cv-qualifiers with array syntax and containing proposal to remove it completely, but I just can't find the link...

Comment: Ah, that would be nice to see. Anyway, this was just a small curiosity that have now been fully answered to me by the community, but if you happen to stumble upon it, feel free to ping me in an additional comment here. Thanks!